# Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error.

```
$.fn.scroller = function(targetid){
this.on('click', function(event) {

            var target = $("#" + this.getAttribute('data-scroll'));

         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
    });
    return this;};
```

Comment: `target.offset()` appears to be `undefined`. It's up to you find the reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason `offset` returns `undefined` is if you call it on a jQuery set that's empty. So apparently, `$("#" + this.getAttribute('data-scroll'))` returned an empty set.

You'll want to add a guard. In fact, I'd probably add two:

```
$.fn.scroller = function(targetid) {
    this.on('click', function(event) {
        var id = this.getAttribute('data-scroll') || ""; // ***
        if (id) {                                        // ***
            var target = $("#" + id);
            if (target[0]) {                             // ***
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }                                            // ***
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

or more concisely and efficiently:

```
$.fn.scroller = function(targetid) {
    this.on('click', function(event) {
        var id = this.getAttribute('data-scroll');
        var target = id && document.getElementById(id);
        if (target) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

Comment: thanks...it worked